# Pandas to_csv skipping the first row of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a Panda DataFrame which has `1646 X 26` shape. But when I am trying to write the fame in a csv file, the first row is getting skipped. I am getting `1645 X 26` shape in the csv file. So I looked up in the internet and I saw some solutions like using `header = False, header = None, header = 0`. So I was following the solutions. But it got worse. Now I after using those solutions, the shape of the csv file is `1644 X 26`.

I believe `to_csv()` is considering the first row as header. So I implicitly tried changing the header name like this:

I took all the column name of my dataframe by writing this:
`cols = list(_df.columns.values)`

Then in the `to_csv()` I wrote like this:

`_df.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'fantasy_data.csv', sep = ',', index = False, header = cols)`

But it is still the same!!

**Note**
If  I run `_df.head()`, it returns the first row!

How to change this so that I can get all the data and `to_csv()` won't skip any row?

Comment: How working `_df.to_csv(path_or_buf = 'fantasy_data.csv', sep = ',', index = False, header = None)`  ?

Comment: It returns 1644 X 26 shape

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you want omit header or not?

Answer (score 4):

**Sample**:

```
_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (_df)
   A  B  C  D
0  a  4  7  1
1  b  5  8  3
2  c  4  9  5
3  d  5  4  7
4  e  5  2  1
5  f  4  3  0
```

---

```
print (_df.shape)
(6, 4)


#if need omit header and index in csv
print(_df.to_csv(sep = ',', index = False, header = None))
a,4,7,1
b,5,8,3
c,4,9,5
d,5,4,7
e,5,2,1
f,4,3,0

if want omit only index
print(_df.to_csv(sep = ',', index = False))
A,B,C,D
a,4,7,1
b,5,8,3
c,4,9,5
d,5,4,7
e,5,2,1
f,4,3,0
```

Comment: actually, what do you mean by header? The label of the columns?

Comment: @sphoenix - yes, exactly.

Comment: it doesn't matter actually. I tried keeping the header and omitting it. But I am not getting the first row. From your example, my `to_csv` always omitting the row `a,4,7,1`. The csv file starts showing from 2nd row till the end

Comment: It is weird, what is `df.head()` or `df.info()` ?

Comment: `df.head()` does return the first row :|

Comment: Also what is `print (df.index.name)` and print `(df.columns.name)` ? Is there empty row under labels of columns?

Comment: both of them return `None`!! Does it mean I have an empty row under columns? But how could this happen?

Comment: If return `None` is is good. there is no empty row. I have no another idea, it should working nice, but in my opinion it is some data related problem.

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: OK, if remove all rows without first 3, still same problem?

Comment: actually it doesn't matter the number of rows, it is always skipping the first row!!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by the following steps.
First, read the csv file using pandas.read_csv and assign attribute "header=None".
Second, when applying to_csv assign the header and index attributes as following "header=["col1","col2","col3"], index=False".
Using this way the first row is not skipped.